# Large number of objects in python (autobahn websocket)

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn, autobahnws

I am using autobahn websockets for my project and I got to know that it creates an instance for a particular websocket connection. But when I will have a large number of connections say in millions, how can I manage these many objects?

1. Should I serialize and then deserialize the objects on runtime?